# Kentico 9 Global setting was not found for key name

Tags: c#, kentico, avalara

I am trying to create settings for a custom module. I am upgrading from Version 8 to version 9. The code worked fine for version 8. I am testing the code on default2.aspx. Here is my code and error:

Error:

> Global setting was not found for key name 'AvalaraJMALicenseKeyStartDate'

The code shows the error here:

```
    SettingsKeyInfoProvider.SetSettingsKeyInfo(si);
```

Code:

```
    //Insert new SettingsKey into database
    string siteName = CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteName;
    int siteID = CMS.SiteProvider.SiteContext.CurrentSiteID;
    DataSet sites = CMS.SiteProvider.SiteInfoProvider.GetSites();

    /// <summary>
    /// creates custom settings for JMA Kentico Software in settings area of site manager
    /// </summary>
    public void CreateAvalaraSettings()
    {

        //create the avalara category, if it doesn't exist
        SettingsCategoryInfo category = SettingsCategoryInfoProvider.GetSettingsCategoryInfoByName("JMA.Avalara");
        if (category == null)
        {
            SettingsCategoryInfo se = new SettingsCategoryInfo();
            se.CategoryName = "JMA.Avalara";
            se.CategoryDisplayName = "Avalara";
            SettingsCategoryInfoProvider.SetSettingsCategoryInfo(se);
        }

        #region avalara settings

        //if the setting does not exist, then create it
        if (SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetSettingsKeyInfo(siteName + ".AvalaraJMALicenseKeyStartDate", siteID) == null)
        {
            // Create and set up new SettingsKey
            SettingsKeyInfo si = new SettingsKeyInfo();
            si.KeyName = siteName + ".AvalaraJMALicenseKeyStartDate";
            si.KeyDisplayName = "AvalaraJMALicenseKeyStartDate";
            si.KeyDescription = "AvalaraJMALicenseKeyStartDate";
            si.KeyType = "string";
            si.KeyDefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            si.KeyValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            si.SiteID = siteID;
            si.KeyIsGlobal = false;
            si.KeyCategoryID = category.CategoryID;
            SettingsKeyInfoProvider.SetSettingsKeyInfo(si);

        }
```

Comment: At which line are you getting the error? When is the code executed/called (app init or somewhere else)?

Comment: What you're receiving is not an error, it's stating it can't find that key.  One thing I noticed right away was your key category name, it should not be prefixed with `CMS`.  You should use your own namespace and not the `CMS` namespace as documentation states.  Second, where is the `siteName` variable populated and is it populated with the correct value?

Comment: Hi, I have made the adjustments and I said what line throws the error. My issue still persists. Am I still checking global settings?

Comment: OK, I solved it. You need to remove this code: si.SiteID = siteID;

Comment: Can you add it as an answer and mark it correct please?

Answer (score 0):

I removed this code and it worked:

```
si.SiteID = siteID;
si.KeyIsGlobal = false;
```